# Ext JS grid filter

Tags: extjs

I am using Ext JS 5.x version grid within my application & using its filter plugin.
Currently on every key press the grid is filtering the records (which is default) but I want to stop the keypress event and only filter the data when user is done giving the filter text and presses Enter key.
I tried to get the handle of filter text box but couldn't resolve it. TIA

Comment: can you put in a fiddle.what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/grid/filtered-buffered-store.html) is what you are looking for.